# ngStyle and ngClass in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm not sure how to use `ngStyle` directive with latest beta-12. Could someone please clarify.

The plnkr link in Angular docs https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/NgStyle-directive.html is outdated, it uses alpha build.

I tried these syntax but does not seem to work. I

```
 [ngStyle]="{'display': none}"
 [style.display]="none"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/U9EJuIhFqxY9t2sULMdw

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngStyle]="{'display': none}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h2 [style.display]="none">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In both cases, `none` should be `'none'` with quotes. Because you should be assigning `string` value to the property `display`. `none` (without qoutes) will be evaluated at runtime and return `undefined` which is not an acceptable value of the css property `display`

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h2 [style.display]="'none'">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

[Here is your plunker fixed](http://plnkr.co/edit/cc6bJE2EulekocENNPTb?p=preview)

**Update**

This is from angular2 docs for [NgClass directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

> The result of an expression evaluation is interpreted differently
>   depending on type of the expression evaluation result:
>
> **string** - all the CSS classes listed in a string (space delimited) are
>   added
>   **Array** - all the CSS classes (Array elements) are added
>   **Object** -
>   each key corresponds to a CSS class name while values are interpreted
>   as expressions evaluating to Boolean. If a given expression evaluates
>   to true a corresponding CSS class is added - otherwise it is removed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  styles:['.hide{display:none}',
  '.border{border:3px solid blue}',
  '.redBack{background-color:red}'
  ],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h2 [style.display]="'none'">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <h2 [ngClass]="'redBack'">Hello {{name}}</h2>  // just normal string
      <h2 [ngClass]="{'hide':hideFlag}">Hello {{name}}</h2>  // will add class 'hide' if hideFlag is true
      <h2 [ngClass]="mulClasses">Hello {{name}}</h2>  // will add an array of classes ['border','redBack']
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  hideFlag = false;
  mulClasses = ['border','redBack']

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

[here is the example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSBKuAf9Sx0In52emFaQ?p=preview)

Comment: @Sudhakar, You are welcome, and I have updated my answer for reference

Comment: Upvote for the reference to the docs, a plnkr and a good explanation!

Comment: @EricMartinez Very appreciated